# In C++ are simple initializations of built-in type immune to the static initialization order fiasco?

Tags: c++, static-initialization, static-order-fiasco

I know about the [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) in C++ and the
[construct on first use idiom](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order-on-first-use) to avoid it.  Thus in the code below
the global assignment of `a` may happen before that of `foo::a` and so
the value of `a` is undefined.  One the other hand, the global
assignment of `b` is OK, since it invoked the function `foo::b()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// foo.hpp

class foo {
public:
  static const string a;
  static const string& b();
  static const char* const c;
  static const char* const d[2];
  static const int e;
  static const int f[2];
};

// foo.cpp

const string foo::a("astr");
const string& foo::b() {
  static const string t("bstr");
  return t;
}
const char* const foo::c = "cstr";
const char* const foo::d[2] = {"dstr1", "dstr2"};
const int foo::e = 5;
const int foo::f[2] = {6, 7};

// main.cpp

// global initializations
string a = foo::a;              // dangerous, might be "" or "astr"
string b = foo::b();            // safe, guaranteed to be "bstr"
const char* c = foo::c;         // what about these...?
const char* d = foo::d[0];
int e = foo::e;
int f = foo::f[0];

int main() {
  cout << a << " " << b << "\n"
       << c << " " << d << "\n"
       << e << " " << f << "\n";
}
```

(Imagine I've combined `foo.hpp`, `foo.cpp`, and `main.cpp` here.)
However what about variables which are built-in types or arrays of them?
Thus are global assignments of `c`, `d`, `e`, and `f` safe in this code?
It seems possible that the linker can set the memory for these variables
so no initialization needs to take place at run time.  But can I rely on
this?

I know I shouldn't be using global variables.  However, I'm the author
of a library (foo.cpp and foo.hpp) and I have no control over what a
user of my library (the author of main.cpp) does.

Comment: Why do you need to have global variables at all? That's a clear sign for a seriously flawed OOP design.

Comment: There are no order issues in your code because there are no dependencies (that is, no initialisation of a variable uses any other variables). Being or not being of a primitive type has nothing to do with it.

Comment: if you cant rely on that then what can you rely on?  did you compile and run your code?  if so then did anything happen to make you think the compiler isnt reliable?  if so then what?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: There are no global variables here, what are you complaining about?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: that's just ridiculous.

Comment: @BenVoigt Static class members are not much better than global variables, no?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: They fall somewhere in between global variables with internal linkage and global variables with external linkage, in terms of badness.  But there's nothing wrong with global variables with internal linkage, placed in the implementation file that uses them, either.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: And even if they were global variables (which they aren't), and even if global variables were a clear sign of a seriously flawed OOP design, C++ is not a language that's limited to OOP designs, and OOP does not have a monopoly on effective design techniques.

Comment: @BenVoigt Okeh! I surrender in front of the [spanish inquisition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nf_Y4MbUCLY) ;-)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Haha!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is the difference between "`static` initialization" (formally known using the language of the Standard as *dynamic initialization of objects with static storage duration* which has the ordering fiasco) and *static initialization*.

The Standard says (section `[basic.start.static]`) that

> A constant initializer for an object `o` is an expression that is a constant expression, except that it may also invoke `constexpr` constructors for `o` and its subobjects even if those objects are of non-literal class types.  [ Note: Such a class may have a non-trivial destructor — end note ]
>
> Constant initialization is performed:
>
> - if each full-expression (including implicit conversions) that appears in the initializer of a reference with static or thread storage duration is a constant expression and the reference is bound to a glvalue designating an object with static storage duration, to a temporary object or subobject thereof, or to a function;
> - if an object with static or thread storage duration is initialized by a constructor call, and if the initialization full-expression is a constant initializer for the object;
> - if an object with static or thread storage duration is not initialized by a constructor call and if either the object is value-initialized or every full-expression that appears in its initializer is a constant expression.
>
> If constant initialization is not performed, a variable with static storage duration or thread storage duration is zero-initialized. **Together, zero-initialization and constant initialization are called static initialization; all other initialization is dynamic initialization. Static initialization shall be performed before any dynamic initialization takes place.**

Your `c`, `d`, `e`, and `f` objects have constant initializers, so their initialization is completed during the static initialization phase (even though `c` and `d` are NOT themselves constant), and their values are available during all dynamic initialization, even those that came lexically before.

Comment: Thanks.  And I suppose that `a` is excluded from this rule because it doesn't have static storage duration?

Comment: @cffk: It does have static storage duration, but it does not qualify as constant initialization, because it falls outside the permission in the first sentence "it may also invoke constexpr constructors for `o` and its subobjects", since the `std::string` converting constructor being used is not `constexpr`.  So it will get zero-initialized during the static initialization phase, and the constructor call will run during dynamic initialization phase.  Only at the constructor call does the object's lifetime begin.

Comment: @cffk: So you see, you weren't that far off talking about primitive types and simple expressions... other types and expressions are allowed too but pretty much only when `constexpr` keyword kicks in.